# converting hex to decimal with bash

Tags: bash

I've seen some strange things.
I tried to convert hex to dec with **bash Shell**

I used very very simple command.

```
$ g_receiverBeforeToken=1158e460913d00000
$ echo $((16#$g_receiverBeforeToken))
1553255926290448384
```

As you guys know, this result should be '20000000000000000000'.

When I put in any other hex number, it was correct. But only **1553255926290448384** was weird.

Comment: So you're saying, for example, `1553255926290448383` works fine? By the way, are you aware that `20000000000000000000` is greater than 2**64? The word size on your machine is probably 64 bits. 64 bits is 16 hexadecimal digits. `1158e460913d00000` is 17 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just that number, it's any number over 7fffffffffffffff, because it's using 64-bit integers and that's the largest one. 16-digit numbers over that wrap around and become negative (because of [two's complement representation of signed integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):

```
$ echo $((16#7fffffffffffffff))
9223372036854775807
$ echo $((16#7fffffffffffffff + 1))
-9223372036854775808
$ echo $((16#8000000000000000))
-9223372036854775808
```

Past ffffffffffffffff (aka -1), it wraps back to zero:

```
$ echo $((16#ffffffffffffffff))
-1
$ echo $((16#ffffffffffffffff + 1))
0
$ echo $((16#10000000000000000))
0
```

Net result: only the last 16 hex digits actually matter; anything past that gets dropped off the high end of the 64-bit integer representation:

```
$ echo $((16#0000000000000010))
16
$ echo $((16#10000000000000010))
16
$ echo $((16#ffffffff0000000000000010))
16
```

Since 1553255926290448384 is 17 digits long, the first digit is being dropped off in this way:

```
$ echo $((16#1158e460913d00000))
1553255926290448384
$ echo $((16#158e460913d00000))
1553255926290448384
$ echo $((16#121345158e460913d00000))
1553255926290448384
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you are looking to do using `bc` as a base conversion with a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## validate sufficient input
test -n "$1" || {
    printf "\n error: insufficient input. usage:  %s num [obase (2)] [ibase (10)]\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

## test for help
test "$1" = "-h" || test "$1" = "--help" && {
    printf "\n  usage:  %s num [obase (2)] [ibase (10)] -- to convert number\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 0
}

## validate numeric value given for conversion (bash only test)
ival="${1^^}"
[[ $ival =~ [^0-9A-F] ]] && {
    printf "\n error: invalid input. Input must be within upper/lower case hex character set [0-9A-Fa-f]\n\n"
    exit 1
}

ob=${2:-2}
ib=${3:-10}

# set obase first before ibase -- or weird things happen.
printf "obase=%d; ibase=%d; %s\n" $ob $ib $ival | bc
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash hex2dec.sh -h

  usage:  hex2dec.sh num [obase (2)] [ibase (10)] -- to convert number
```

Using your example:

```
$ bash hex2dec.sh 1158e460913d00000 10 16
20000000000000000000
```

Also handy if you want it in binary as well:

```
$ bash hex2dec.sh 1158e460913d00000 2 16
10001010110001110010001100000100100010011110100000000000000000000
```

Comment: I get bad substitution error on `ival="${1^^}"` when I tried this on Mac

Comment: That is part of bash that converts all values in the first positional parameter to all upper-case. What does `bash --version` show on your mac? It is in `man bash` under the heading `${parameter^^pattern}` under the broader section of `Parameter Expansion`. It has been part of bash as a while. Are you sure you are not using `#!/bin/sh` or running it as `sh scriptname`? Also what does `echo $SHELL` show?

Comment: thank you, yeah this Mac OS is bash 3.2; I think the upper case conversion is only avail in bash 4+... I used `tr` instead in this case, seems to work now. One additional question, I'm not too familiar wth `bc`, but if I wanted to convert a hex string to a base-62 alphanumeric string, how might I use your script? Specifically I'm trying to reduce an md5 hash to a shorter base-62 string (and revert it back to the md5 later)

Comment: If you your input is base 10 and you want output base 62, you can use `bc` again. For example `printf "obase=%d; ibase=%d; %s\n" $ob $ib $val | bc` where `ob=62` and `ib=10` and `val` is whatever value you want to convert from base 10 to base 62. (adjust your `ib` as needed)

Comment: thanks for this clarification, it was really an issue of me not being familiar with bc; for one I wanted to pass characters directly to bc; still havent figured that out yet and resorted to summing the positional values together rather than trying to do the conversion directly.